# google maps api v3 google street view and google Street View Static Image

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Google enables us to retrieve a static street view image

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10

I am building a real estate database that incorporates Google Maps Api v3 with Street View Panoramas.

If you go to this url bit.ly/17A6r4P you will see and example i made in order to be more clear. The images displayed are the Static Street View Image generated developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview * If you click on "Map" the google maps street view will open but i want the default view in Street View Panorama in Google Maps to be the same as the "Static Image"
Dead on the front of the house.

Comment: Where are you wanting the static image to be loaded? Are you thinking that the left side of the screen is street view and the right is images of the houses?

Comment: Also, it's a little unclear to me what your question really is. Are you asking about how to translate position from google street view into coordinates that you could use to lookup house information?

Answer (score 3):

The information you need is in the URL 
location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10

Use that to initialize a Google Maps Javascript API v3 Streetview:

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_Streetview_lookAtC.html?location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10)

proof of concept code snippet:

```js
var urlstring = 'location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10';
// If there are any parameters at eh end of the URL, they will be in  location.search
// looking something like  "?marker=3"

var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
var panorama;
var heading;
var pitch;

function initialize() {
  // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
  var query = urlstring; // location.search.substring(1);

  // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
  var pairs = query.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
    var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
    var argname = pairs[i].substring(0, pos).toLowerCase();
    var value = pairs[i].substring(pos + 1).toLowerCase();

    // process each possible argname  -  use unescape() if theres any chance of spaces
    if (argname == "location") {
      var coords = value.split(",");
      lat = parseFloat(coords[0]);
      lng = parseFloat(coords[1]);
    }
    if (argname == "pitch") {
      pitch = parseFloat(value);
    }
    if (argname == "heading") {
      heading = parseFloat(value);
    }
    if (argname == "lat") {
      lat = parseFloat(value);
    }
    if (argname == "lng") {
      lng = parseFloat(value);
    }
  }
  if (!isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lng)) {
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  }
  // Set up the map
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: myLatLng,
    streetViewControl: false
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    myOptions);

  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"));

  sv.getPanoramaByLocation(myLatLng, 50, processSVData);
}

function processSVData(data, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: data.location.latLng,
      draggable: true,
      map: map,
      title: data.location.description
    });

    panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
    if (isNaN(heading))
      heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(data.location.latLng, myLatLng);
    if (isNaN(pitch)) pitch = 0;
    // alert(data.location.latLng+":"+myLatLng+":"+heading);
    panorama.setPov({
      heading: heading,
      pitch: pitch,
      zoom: 1
    });
    panorama.setVisible(true);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

      var markerPanoID = data.location.pano;
      // Set the Pano to use the passed panoID
      panorama.setPano(markerPanoID);
      panorama.setPov({
        heading: 270,
        pitch: 0,
        zoom: 1
      });
      panorama.setVisible(true);
    });
  } else {
    alert("Street View data not found for this location.");
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="display:none; width: 425px; height: 400px;float:left"></div>
<div id="pano" style="width: 425px; height: 400px;float:left"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You very much for your time. Unfortunately due for accuracy reasons i have no other option but to geocode instead of using the already existing coordinates in our database....Thank You, still learning.

Comment: that was unbelievably kind thank you.

Comment: I have a new map and a new problem with getting geolocation consistently running correctly without errors or displaying the map with no markers. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

http://bocashoy.com/map/

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is a new question.

Answer (score -1):

You would want to use [Google Maps Street View API.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/)

> The Google Street View Image API lets you embed a static
>   (non-interactive) Street View panorama or thumbnail into your web
>   page, without the use of JavaScript. The viewport is defined with URL
>   parameters sent through a standard HTTP request, and is returned as a
>   static image

Comment: If  you go to this url
http://bit.ly/17A6r4P
you will see and example i made in order to be more clear.
The images displayed are the Static Street View Image generated
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/

* If you click on "Map" the google maps street view will open but i want the default view in Street View to be the same as the "Static Image"